# Unique string attribute with special character

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a field `registration` in my migration file and it looks like this:

```
$table->string('registration')->unique();
```

but when I have similar, but not exactly the same one strings, it breaks. It looks like that the problem is with special char and this two strings are the same `BG 863 ČŠ` and `BG 863 ČS` but it should not be.

Comment: `Š` and `S` is not same

Comment: not the same but somehow db don't know that

Comment: What is your database collation set to?

Comment: I don't understand a question :( I use mysql with utf8 encoding

Comment: Your database should have a set character-set and collation. Please try to figure out how it's set for you :)